# Gallery returns old file name

Tags: android, gallery, onactivityresult

I send Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Media"), CameraUtils.REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

I get result and rename file

```
case CameraUtils.REQUEST_GALLERY:
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    String fileName = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
    File from = new File(fileName);
    String directory = from.getParent();
    File to = new File(directory, "newFile" + i + ".jpg");
    from.renameTo(to);
    i++;
```

The old file name was /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100LGDSC/CAM00046.jpg, the new file name is "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100LGDSC/newFile1.jpg".
Then again i send Intent and get same file, but file name is "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100LGDSC/CAM00046.jpg", and not "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100LGDSC/newFile1.jpg".
Why?

Comment: I know that there are thumbnails, maybe they can be updated?

Answer (score 0):

hope this work :
add below code  to your program:

```
this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

your code will be like :

```
case CameraUtils.REQUEST_GALLERY:
Uri uri = data.getData();
this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
String fileName = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
File from = new File(fileName);
String directory = from.getParent();
File to = new File(directory, "newFile" + i + ".jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
i++;
```